# opencart currency value problem (Very interesting)

Tags: php, opencart, currency, opencart2.x

I use USD as default currency and set it to 1.0000. When i try to set other currencies TRY and EUR, something happens.

I enter 0.8662 for EUR and 5.4000 for TRY. But when i hit save and go to main currency screen, they set different values.

0.86619997 for EUR and 5.40000010. Is this normal? Where is the problem? How can i fix it?

I hang a scrren. Could you please help me about this? Thanks.

[currency problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT23a.jpg)

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf

Comment: http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html

Comment: @Alen Not a 100% sure but didnt opencart have a auto calculate value function on the top of the page?